# How do I join two tables from a database in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I'm currently working on a project where we have to join two tables in SQL and then create a page to show the result of the two tables combined.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    ANIMAL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    FOOD_PORTION
ON
    ANIMAL = FOOD_PORTION
```

and then a second page where the outcome should be:

```
CREATE TABLE ANIMAL(
    AnimalID        CHAR(5)         PRIMARY KEY,
    AnimalName      CHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    Species         CHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    Weight          INT             NOT NULL,
    DOB             DATE            NOT NULL,
    ExhibitID       CHAR(5)         REFERENCES EXHIBIT(ExhibitID)
);


CREATE TABLE FOOD_PORTION(
    PortionSize     INT             NOT NULL,
    AnimalID        CHAR(5)         REFERENCES ANIMAL(AnimalID)
);

SELECT C.Name
FROM   ANIMAL AS C
UNION
SELECT S.Name
FROM   FOOD_PORTION AS S
```

Comment: From a schema perspective you probably want `id` columns to be `INT` or `BIGINT` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` not some arbitrary `CHAR(5)` column. Things like `AnimalID` are good candidates for a secondary (`UNIQUE`) index.

Comment: your first query is correct except you have  to mention join condition whihc will `On ANIMAL.AnimalId = Food_Portion.AnimalID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you need.  Using tadman's suggestion to change the char column to INT.  Also changing the CHAR to VARCHAR columns.

I also made the ID's in each table Identity columns (so they will auto populate).

```
CREATE TABLE ANIMAL(
    AnimalID        INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    AnimalName      VARCHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    Species         VARCHAR(50)        NOT NULL,
    Weight          INT             NOT NULL,
    DOB             DATE            NOT NULL,
    ExhibitID       CHAR(5)         REFERENCES EXHIBIT(ExhibitID)
);


CREATE TABLE FOOD_PORTION(
    PortionSize     INT IDENTITY,
    AnimalID        INT         REFERENCES ANIMAL(AnimalID)
);

SELECT A.*, FP.*
FROM Animal A 
INNER JOIN Food_Portion FP ON A.AnimalID = FP.AnimalID
```

Comment: @mmcodes If that worked could you please mark the answer as the solution please.  Thank You and glad I could help